# JS Event listener not working with classes

Tags: javascript

I have created some event through JS, when I ever I hover my mouse over the input element, JS should add some classes to that element so that new CSS properties should be applied through tailwind. I don't know why it is not working properly.
I have linked the script tag before the ending body tag and tried to place it after it too but it still did not work.

```js
document.querySelector(".rating-btn1").addEventListener("onmouseover", function() {
  document.querySelector(".rating-btn1").classList.remove("bg-gray-circle");
  document.querySelector(".rating-btn1").classList.add("bg-light-gray-custom");
});
```

```html
<input type="button" name="rating" value="1" class="rating-btn1 rounded-full bg-gray-circle px-4 py-2 text-light-gray-custom hover:cursor-pointer" />
```

Comment: Don't use an event listener for this. Use CSS with the `:hover` modifier.

Comment: Or even more straight-forward, since you're using Tailwind, the utility class `hover:bg-light-gray-custom` will do the job.

Comment: You do not use "on" with addEventListener event names

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your event listener. It should be `mouseover` not `onmouseover`.

```js
document.querySelector(".rating-btn1").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  document.querySelector(".rating-btn1").classList.remove("bg-gray-circle");
  document.querySelector(".rating-btn1").classList.add("bg-light-gray-custom");
});
```